# How do I add an audio track to my "Play To" list using C# in Windows 7?

Tags: c#, windows-7, automation, windows-media-player

I poked around for a while on Google and Windows Media player looking for a way to do this, but I can't and I think I should be able to, so I'm asking the fine people of StackOverflow.

I'd like to be able to write some code to do one of the following:

1. Add an audio file from my WMP media library to the current "Play To" playlist.
2. Add an audio file from the file system to the current "Play To" playlist.

It doesn't really matter to me which of these I use for my approach. Can anyone give me some direction? I'm guessing I'm going to have to dig into the Windows Media Player DLLs, but a starting point would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no easy way to do this. I guess you could try wrapping [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd368787(VS.85).aspx) in C#, but it isn't that documented.

Comment: Arghhh...you'd think that they would open up features like this to .NET developers.

Comment: @Ed- Yep. I tried controlling WMP (the actual one, not an instance control) via C# and failed miserably. It seems even _with_ C++, it's still not as easy as you would hope it would be.